# jquery or javascript trim or substr

Tags: javascript, substring

```
var str='userkwd* type:"Office"';
```

How do I trim or substr or slice this string to only get `'userkwd'`? Also the variable will have quotes as part of it..This one is tricky as if there is no userkwd .i.e. if

```
var str=' type:"Office"';
```

it should return null. The * gets appended with userkwd from inputbox..

```
str.slice(0,str.indexOf('*'));  ???

str.split("*")[0];   ????

str.substring(0, str.indexOf('*'));   ???
```

Which one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
str.replace(/\*? type.*/, '');
```

Answer (score 0):

The answer is trivial. Think if userkwd can contain " ", for example "user kwd". If so, then you cannot use split(" "). If userkwd could contain additional * like user*kwd then you cannot  use this character. If the keyword could contain both spaces and * then you should use different method, for example some more complicated regular expression, but try to evalute your suggested methods first.

By the way, in the scenario you have given `var str=' type:"Office"';` there is no userkwd at all, there is also no *, so you definitely should not use * if this is valid example. Space seaprator however holds, so I would go for it if possible.

You can also try to find the last occurance of "type:" and get everything what is before it, if empty then change it to null, or something like this. There are really a lot of possibilities, we do not have enough information why you need this functionality and what could be the input...